# pandas get counts based on previous column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add column to a pandas dataframe where the value is an incrementing value starting with a value from another column. For instance say I have the following dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['a', 1], ['b', 5], ['c', 10], ['c', 10], ['c', 10]], columns=['x', 'y'])
df

    x   y
0   a   1
1   a   1
2   b   5
3   c   10
4   c   10
5   c   10
```

Is there some pandas functionality that would return a series that is an increasing value for each group? in other words `'a'` would start with `1`, `'b'` with `5` and `'c'` with `10`. The output series would be `(1, 2, 5, 10, 11, 12)` so it could be added to the original dataframe like so:

```
    x   y   z
0   a   1   1
1   a   1   2
2   b   5   5
3   c   10  10
4   c   10  11
5   c   10  12
```

I tried the following:

```
z = []
for start, length in zip(df.y.unique(), df.groupby('x').agg('count')['y']):
    z.append(list(range(start, length + start)))
np.array(z).flatten()
z

[[1, 2], [5], [10, 11, 12]]
```

This doesn't quite get what I need, I'm not sure why the array does not flatten and it seems overly complex for a seemingly simple task.

EDIT: 
The solution should be extendable to more complex dataframes as well, for instance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 5], ['c', 10], ['d', 5]], columns=['x', 'y'])
df = df.append([df]*(50),ignore_index=True)
```

Where both the `'a'` and `'b'` values in column 'x' are eqaul to 5. In both of those instances the counting should start at 5

Comment: Use `z.extend(range(start, length + start))` instead of `z.append...`

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
df['z'] = df.y + df.groupby('y').apply(lambda df: pd.Series(range(len(df)))).values
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however it doesn't extend to more complex cases. I updated the questiion to clarify what I mean. The solution in my question does not account for this either, but I'm stuck on how to accomplish it

Comment: Based on your suggestions this `df['z'] = df.groupby('x').apply(lambda x: x['y'] + range(len(x))).values` seems to accomplish what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

While not a pandas related answer, to get out of the nested lists, and flatten it out, you can use a simple list comprehension from what you currently have as z.

```
>>>z = [[1, 2], [5], [10, 11, 12]]
>>>z_flat = [num for sublist in z for num in sublist])
>>>z_flat
[1, 2, 5, 10, 11, 12]
```

EDIT: of for a faster conversion, you can use itertools.chain()

```
In [5]: import itertools 

In [6]: z
Out[6]: [[1, 2], [5], [10, 11, 12]]

In [7]: merged = list(itertools.chain(*z))

In [8]: merged
Out[8]: [1, 2, 5, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way uglier method compared to @piRSquared's:

```
def func(group):
    x = group['y'].head(1).values
    l = []
    for i in range(len(group)):
        l.append(x+i)
    return pd.Series(l, name='z')

x = df.groupby('x').apply(func).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
x['z'] = x['z'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
pd.concat([df, x['z']], axis=1)
```